To talk in a heavy manner
https://youtu.be/9CrGRaA7jr0?feature=shared
This is a link for a youtube video of General Sam Manekshaw's speech on “Leadership”.
General Manekshaw has been my role model since I first got to know about him. Only recently, when I decided to join the Indian Army as an officer, I thought I should improve myself or make a Manekshaw out of me.
The problem is I do not know what to improve on (please do tell), how to be like those witty and charismatic British officers that I have seen in many movies of the 1914-18 and 1939-45 world?
So, I thought to start with 'speaking like Sam as he did in the video'. Things I observed :
His vocabulary was vibrant and his thoughts were inspiring, his pronunciation was posh (I am assuming that was because his job required him to talk to people from overseas), his talk was engaging and had occasional hints of humor.
How do learn to talk like him ? (I understand that this skill is not purely linguistic and other attributes are required, well then how do I improve up on those attributes?)

General Manekshaw’s first assignment in the military was to a British unit, so I would assume he adopted their accent and way of speaking.

By “heavy” manner, do you mean “serious,” perhaps, or maybe distinguished?

As it stands, this appears to be a request for character development and not a question of language.

I’m voting to close this question because it is a request for resources / instruction. Possibly a better fit on 'Interpersonal Skills.SE'.

The word you are looking for is elocution: Elocution is the study of formal speaking in pronunciation, grammar, style, and tone as well as the idea and practice of effective speech and its forms. (Wikipedia). Now that you know the word, you can find the resources. (PS: If you recast your question as a search for a term to fit your description, it could be reopened.)
